# duplicate class error .R and .Buildconfig in Phonegap project

Tags: cordova, android-studio, phonegap-build

We are using the latest Android Studio (1.3.1) and we are trying to compile a Phonegap project (with nodejs: 0.12.7) inside this development environment.

For setting up this environment we did all the steps described here:

http://www.codenutz.com/getting-started-phonegap-android-studio/

But when trying to build the project we got two errors:

> Error:(10, 14) java: duplicate class: OUR_PROJECT_NAME.R Error:(4, 14)
>   java: duplicate class: OUR_PROJECT_NAME.BuildConfig

Any idea how we can avoid the **duplicate class error** for the two files?

Thanks for a hint.

Best Regards

Frank

Answer (score 1):

While checking Project Settings -> Modules we found the root cause.

After Importing the project to Android Studio somehow an additional folder was added to the Source Folders.

[image: Project Settings -> Modules]

Once **this entry was deleted** the project could be build successful :-).